# Imiplenting panGesture on a viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

From a tabBarController, I'm presenting a new viewController modally. I want to implement a panGestureRecognizer on it so that the user can drag down on the viewController to close it. However, I have a scrollview embedded in the modal viewcontroller making this a bit more difficult.

My code so far makes for a very cheap solution:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        self.scrollview.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(scrollview.panGestureRecognizer)
} 

func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .Changed:
        handlePanChanged(recognizer); break
    case .Ended:
        handlePanTerminated(recognizer); break
    case .Cancelled:
        handlePanTerminated(recognizer); break
    case .Failed:
        handlePanTerminated(recognizer); break
    default: break
    }
}

func handlePanChanged(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        var translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        println("moving")
        view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y + translation.y);
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }


}

func handlePanTerminated(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer!) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        let offset = self.view.center.y - view.center.y
        let vel = recognizer.velocityInView(self.view).y

        if (fabs(offset) > kTriggerDistance) || (fabs(vel) > kTriggerVelocity) {
            let pointsToMove = self.pointsToMove(view, angle: 0, direction: vel > 0 ? .Down : .Up)
            let animationDuration = NSTimeInterval(min(0.3, pointsToMove / Float(vel)))

            UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
                view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x, view.center.y + CGFloat(pointsToMove))
                }, completion: { (completed) -> Void in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                    view.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.75,
                initialSpringVelocity: 2.0, options: nil, animations: { () -> Void in
                    view.center = self.view.center
                }, completion: nil);
        }
    }
}
```

Although this allows me to drag around the scrollView, I'm really stuck on how to drag around the entire viewController. Do I have to make it a subview on the root view controller?

Comment: Why is this tagged Objective-C?

Comment: You should look into UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013061-CH1-SW5 You'll almost certainly want to watch this video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-218/

Comment: Please don't repost your questions.